# C++ initialize const member with mutator method

Tags: c++

Suppose the following class exists (which I cannot change).

```
class TheirClass {
 public:
  TheirClass();
  TheirClass(const TheirClass&) = delete;
  TheirClass& operator=(const TheirClass&) = delete;
  TheirClass(TheirClass&&) = delete;
  void FinishInitialization();
}
```

I would like to use it in my class like so.

```
class MyClass {
 private:
  const TheirClass their_class_;
}
```

If the copy and move constructors were not deleted, I could do something like this.

```
TheirClass CreateTheirClass() {
  TheirClass their_class;
  their_class.FinishInitialization();
  return their_class;
}

MyClass::MyClass() : their_class_(CreateTheirClass()) {}
```

Currently my solution is to use pointers.

```
class MyClass {
 private:
  const std::unique_ptr<const TheirClass> their_class_;
}
```

```
std::unique_ptr<TheirClass> CreateTheirClass() {
  auto their_class = std::make_unique<TheirClass>();
  their_class->FinishInitialization();
  return their_class;
}

MyClass::MyClass() : their_class_(CreateTheirClass()) {}
```

But this seems to add unnecessary complexity and a needless performance hit (storing the object on the heap rather than the stack).

How can I have a `const TheirClass` as member in my class while still being able to call `TheirClass::FinishInitialization` (once, upon initialization of my class)?

Comment: Declare `FinishInitialization`() as a mutable class member?

Comment: @John3136 default constructor is not deleted.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sorry, forgot to explicitly say that I can't easily modify `TheirClass`.

Comment: So if there is a default ctor why can't you just have an instance on `TheirClass` inside yours and call `FinishInitialization()` somewhere in your constructor ? edit: Ahh, I think I see - cos of the const-ness

Comment: My instance of TheirClass is marked const. This prevents me from calling the non-const method `FinishInitialization()`.

Comment: Are you opposed to using `const_cast<TheirClass&>(their_class_).FinishInitialization()`?

Comment: Isn't that undefined behavior?

Comment: Isn't anything you do going to be UB ? You're trying to call a non-const function on a const object. Whatever you do is going to be some kind of trick that might backfire...

Comment: Potentially -- it depends what `FinishInitialization()` actually does. If it touches members that would be transitively `const`, then it is UB. That said, I think _any_ solution here is going to be UB.

Comment: In this case, I happen to know that FinishInitialization is actually a stand-in for a simple setter method.

Comment: The way I think of it, I'd like to start with a non-const member, call a non-const method on it in the ctor of my class, and then mark that member as const.

Comment: Unfortunately, `const`-ness is rather fixed. My question is: What is the _goal_ of marking your member `their_class_` as `const`?

Comment: FinishInitialization  is a setter ? And you want to call it on a const object ? As I said, anything you do will be a trick. Since it is private in your class why the need to make it const ? Off the top of my head as a thought experiment: could you have a non const instance that you use to FinishInit and have a const reference to it that you use for all your other interactions?

Comment: MyClass is being used in a multithreaded way. const-ness provides some safety if I or another engineer goes and modifies MyClass in the future.

Comment: I'm fairly new to C++ and was just hoping something like this would be possible. I predict the other engineers on my team will prefer the pointer solution to the non-const or const_cast options. Thanks for the discussion!

Comment: Nope, this is not possible. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Do they also delete the move constructor?

Comment: Ah, on the real class I'm working with, it's implicitly deleted. Updated `TheirClass` to reflect this.

Comment: @BarryMcNamara: Does my posted solution work?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a wrapper class that calls `FinishInitialization` in its constructor, but only exposes the instance as a `const`.

```
class TheirClassWrapper final
{
public:
    /// The question didn't specify `args`, but I assume you want them here
    template <typename... Args>
    explicit TheirClassWrapper(Args&&... args)
            : impl_()
    {
        impl_.FinishInitialization(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    const TheirClass& operator*() const noexcept { return impl_; }

    const TheirClass* operator->() const noexcept { return &impl_; }

private:
    TheirClass impl_;
};
```

Use the wrapper instead:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();

    // ...

private:
    const TheirClassWrapper their_class_;
}
```

You then use `their_class_->whatever()` or `*their_class_` to access things. It looks like a pointer, but it will get trivially inlined by your compiler.

---

A potentially more generic solution to this is:

```
template <typename T>
class InitWrapper final
{
public:
    template <typename FInit>
    explicit InitWrapper(FInit&& init)
    {
        init(impl_);
    }

    const T& operator*()  const noexcept { return impl_; }
    const T* operator->() const noexcept { return impl_; }

private:
    T impl_;
};
```

This allows you to run some arbitrary function in the `InitWrapper` constructor, while still only exposing the `const T` view of things.

```
MyClass::MyClass()
        : their_class_([](TheirClass& x) { x.FinishInitialization(); })
{ }
```